# How can I implement collisions in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

My code

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

display_width=640
display_height=480
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.set_caption("Slide!")

pygame.display.update()

background=pygame.image.load("background.png")
walkup=pygame.image.load("up.png")
walkleft=pygame.image.load("left.png")
walkright=pygame.image.load("right.png")
walkdown=pygame.image.load("down.png")
snowball=pygame.image.load("snowball.png")
direction=walkdown
black=(0,0,0)

gameExit=False

fps=60
clock.tick(fps)
font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
ball_x=display_width/3
ball_y=display_height/3
location_x=display_width/2
location_y=display_height/2
moveY=0
moveX=0

step_size=5

class maincharacter (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,*groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=direction
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

class thesnowball (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,*groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=snowball
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

def scoreCount(msg,color):
    printscore=font.render(msg,True,color)
    gameDisplay.blit(printscore,[20,20])

def messagetoscreen(msg,color):
    screen_text=font.render(msg,True,color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text,[display_width/5,display_height/2])

def gameloop():
    direction=walkdown
    timer=1
    startTime=time.time()
    gameExit=False
    gameOver=False    
    location_x=display_width/2
    location_y=display_height/2
    moveY=0
    moveX=0

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver==True:
            messagetoscreen("Press C to continue or Q to quit !",black)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key==pygame.K_q:
                       gameExit=True
                       gameOver=False
                   if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameloop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit=True

            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    direction=walkleft
                    moveX= -step_size
                    moveY=0

                if event.key==pygame.K_d:
                    direction=walkright
                    moveX=step_size
                    moveY=0

                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    direction=walkdown
                    moveY=step_size
                    moveX=0

                if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                    direction=walkup
                    moveY=-step_size
                    moveX=0

        if location_x>=(display_width-40) or location_x<0 or location_y>=(display_height-30) or location_y<-15:
            gameOver=True

        secondsPassed=time.time() - startTime

        if timer==(int(secondsPassed)):
            print(timer)
            timer+=1
        gameDisplay.blit(snowball,(ball_x,ball_y))
        gameDisplay.blit(direction,(location_x,location_y))
        gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
        scoreCount("Score: "+str(int(secondsPassed)),black)
        location_y+=moveY
        location_x+=moveX
        clock.tick(fps)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameloop()
```

As you can see I have the base of the game made. At the moment all I have is a snowball blitting in, however the end goal is to have it move across the screen and have the player avoid it.

I would like to use pygame.sprite.spritecollide or pygame.sprite.collide_rect, however I'm unsure how to do this, as a lot of errors come up, and there really aren't any useful tutorials on how to do it.

Just to be clear, I have the classes made I just cannot implement that into either sprite groups, or into the collide_rect method

thanks

Comment: The pygame [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html) has examples for using most of it's methods as well as tutorials. Have you looked at it and tried using some of them to do this? In other words, post what have you tried that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide()
```

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: I'm really bad at explaining stuff, the pygame link definitely won't change anytime soon, and you could get explanations with a simple google search.